# What sort of bike will suit both offroading and onroading

Tags: mountain-bike, off-road

I live in an area which is connected to main road by a small lane(worse than mountainous region, I mean it's condition) and the main road is just like a new tarmac surface, the speed breakers are something like road blocks half feet in height and half feet in width with triangular surface. My old bike is an mtb and serves both well but it is heavy any suggestions what I should look for in my new bike.

Comment: obv a hybrid; if thats not the A your making no sense -1

Comment: CYCLOCROSS FOR LIFE!!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out cyclocross style bicycle.
It does well on the road and light trails.
You can put touring tires on it.

[wiki Cyclo-cross](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclo-cross)

Comment: The lane i am talking about is just like a mountain with sand and gravel and irregular surface, Also if a shocker was present that would keep my back from aching

Comment: Cyclocross does sand, gravel, and irregular surface. The title is what sort of bike that does off road and on road.  You asked for a suggestion and you got one.

Comment: yeah, +1. A cx bike would be the first thing I'd look at, failing that maybe a light mtb. If you have the luxury of being able to say "today I will ride on the road" or "today I will ride offroad" it would be worth considering two sets of wheels.

Comment: I don't know where you live but at the end of cyclocross season you can find some great deals on used cyclocross bikes.  You have sponsored riders that get a bike for free or at wholesale and sell for wholesale.  In the US the season ends in January.

Comment: I would look at a gravel grinder that has commuting characteristics.  Kona Rove, Surly Cross Check and Straggler, and everything like those that might be lighter but can take fenders and a rack/panniers.

Comment: I've owned a Surly Cross-check for about 6 years now and have ridden on pavement, gravel, sand, snow, ice, mud, grass, and just about everything else imaginable. Definitely look at a cyclocross bike, they're amazingly versatile.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use a hybrid bicycle. 29" wheels with slightly knobby tyres, upright handlebar and some come with a front suspension, though I would select one without.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in similar situation. My solution (since my entire trip is 20 miles one way and only 3 miles are forest trail) is to bear the bumpiness (with stock carbonfork) by putting 700x 35 tires on Trek 7.5 FX which is a road bike biased hybrid. If you go with smaller wheels it gets bumpier. If you go with wider tires than you suffer on pavement.

And yes, as the elders say, if you want to shell out some $ (as opposed to getting decent used bike on Craigslist) buy a cyclocross bike!

Answer (score 0):

Get a lighter mountain bike. You can then get some hybrid tyres if you want better rolling on the road, but you will still be able to do proper mountain biking if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion would be a bike from the emerging "gravel" or "adventure" categories. Typically they are comfortable road bikes with clearance for larger tires, meant to be used on a wide variety of road surfaces, both paved and unpaved.

Answer (score 0):

I would lean toward getting a bike that handles offroad really well.  You can always ride and offroad bike on the road but it is more difficult to ride a onroad bike offroad.

Comment: That is very true paul.!